# MVC 3 routing for unknown urls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes

I want to be able to handle any url that s requested via some controller.

```
foo.com/a
foo.com/abcd
foo.com/x1
```

for foo.com/a

I want to process it with

`UrlHandlerController` with `Process(string url)` method.

How should i add a routing rule to be able to do this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new custom route and use Phill Haack's [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx) to test your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "customroute",
    "{url}", 
    new { controller = "UrlHandler",
        action = "Process",
        url = ""
    }
);
```

Controller:

```
public class UrlHandlerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Process(string url)
    {
        return View();

        /* or */
        if(url == "something"){
            return View("SomethingView");
        }
        else if(url == "somethingelse"){
            return View("SomethingElseView");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why url = UrlParameter.Optional ? is it optional?

Comment: the order of your route mappings matter, place this route first. if you have other routes, highly probable, you'll need to find a way to re-route the request to a default controller — this is why i mentioned the usage of the ***Route Debugger***...

Comment: @Xander would `{*url}` have effect in your answer? Is there any difference between `{url}` and `{*url}`

Comment: @AndreCalil your edit came after my edit and darth's comment — don't be so prudent to edit ...

Comment: I see. Anyway, I didn't knew Route Debugger, nice suggetions.

Comment: well i moved this route to upper. still no luck. i ll try route debugger.

Comment: @DarthVader could you provide the signature of the `Process` action method?

Comment: If you're getting a 404, this probably means you haven't made a view for the Process action.

Comment: `public ActionResult Process(string url)` this is what i have? this is wrong?

Comment: the attribute isn't *necessary*, if excluded it will accept all types of traffic, `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` ...

Comment: well `controller = "UrlHandlerController"` make it `controller = "UrlHandler"` worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Darth, see if this route helps:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomRoute", // Route name
    "{url}", //Route formation
    new { controller = "UrlHandler", action = "Process" }, // Where to send it
    new { keyWord = @"\S+" } // Regex to identify the argument
);
```

Regards.